# How to set a official format of WADL file?

Tags: xml, postman, wadl

My wadl have a format problem.
It gets ns0: at every syntax, so postman cannot read the wadl correctly.
Could anyone help?

http://192.168.1.1:7001/WebService/api/application.wadl?detail=true"/>

Comment: <ns0:application><ns0:doc ns1:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.21.1"/><ns0:doc ns2:hint="This is simplified WADL with user and core resources only. Link: http://192.168.32.192:7001/api/api/application.wadl?detail=true"/><ns0:grammars/><ns0:resources base="http://192.168.32.192:7001/api/api/"><ns0:resource path="/api"><ns0:resource path="/api"><ns0:method id="api" name="POST"><ns0:response><ns0:representation mediaType="application/json"/></ns0:response></ns0:method></ns0:resource></ns0:resource></ns0:resources></ns0:application>

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove all appearances of ns0: